# How to dot product (1,10^{13}) (10^13,1) scipy sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, dot-product

Basically what the title entails.
The two matrices are mostly zeros. And the first is 1 x 9999999999999 and the second is 9999999999999 x 1
When I try to do a dot product I get this.

```
Unable to allocate 72.8 TiB for an array with shape (10000000000000,) and data type int64

Full traceback </br>

    MemoryError: Unable to allocate 72.8 TiB for an array with shape (10000000000000,) and data type int64

In [31]: imputed.dot(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-670cfc69d4cf> in <module>
----> 1 imputed.dot(s)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in dot(self, other)
    357 
    358         """
--> 359         return self * other
    360 
    361     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    478             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    479                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 480             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    481 
    482         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    499 
    500         major_axis = self._swap((M, N))[0]
--> 501         other = self.__class__(other)  # convert to this format
    502 
    503         idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
     32                 arg1 = arg1.copy()
     33             else:
---> 34                 arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
     35             self._set_self(arg1)
     36 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in asformat(self, format, copy)
    320             # Forward the copy kwarg, if it's accepted.
    321             try:
--> 322                 return convert_method(copy=copy)
    323             except TypeError:
    324                 return convert_method()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csc.py in tocsr(self, copy)
    135         idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices),
    136                                     maxval=max(self.nnz, N))
--> 137         indptr = np.empty(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    138         indices = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    139         data = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 72.8 TiB for an array with shape (10000000000000,) and data type int64
```

It seems the scipy is trying to create a temp array.
I am using the .dot method that scipy provides.
I am also open to non-scipy solutions.
Thanks!

Comment: I mean general multiplication. Here I use the sparse matrix dot. Which is similar to what you provided but for sparse matrices.

Comment: So basically the answer is yes

Comment: What code did you use?  `np.dot(A,B)`?  `A.dot(B)`?  `A*B`?  `A@B`?  How much of the `scipy.sparse` docs have you read?

Comment: A.dot(B) and A*B and A.multiply(B)
All produce same error

Comment: Didn't read much of the docs really.

Comment: What's the sparse format for these two matrices? `csr`, `coo`, etc?  A `csr` with (10^13,1) shape will have to have a `intptr` array 10^13 elements long, regardless of the number of nonzero terms.

Comment: The full traceback might help.

Comment: it is a csr. Can you give me some clue on what is an intptr and how to make it like that?

Comment: I can replicate this issue, creating two `csc_matrix` and `a.dot(b)` just jacking up 30GB ram and refuses to continue (without the error).

Comment: Will coo make it better to multiply? because I read that csr is efficient at multiplication.

Comment: @hpaulj added full traceback

Comment: @QuangHoang I am using 
scipy                  1.7.2               
Linux Ubuntu with 32 GB Ram (EC2 instance r5)

Comment: I think you can just loop through the data and manually multiply them.

Comment: @QuangHoang, converting a (1,N) `csc` to `csr` will produce this error; the required `indptr` array is just too large.  I agree that a direct calculation using the respective `data` and `indices` values is the way to go.

Comment: Any ideas about the most efficient way? I am trying to normally loop over the smaller indices and multiplying both cells from both vectors. But it is way too slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [105]: from scipy import sparse
```

If I make a (100,1) csr matrix:

```
In [106]: A = sparse.random(100,1,format='csr')
In [107]: A
Out[107]: 
<100x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The data and indices are:

```
In [109]: A.data
Out[109]: array([0.19060481])
In [110]: A.indices
Out[110]: array([0], dtype=int32)
In [112]: A.indptr
Out[112]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

So even with only 1 nonzero term, one array is large (101).

On the other hand the `csc` format for the same array has a much smaller storage.  But `csc` with (1,100) shape will look like the csr.

```
In [113]: Ac = A.tocsc()
In [114]: Ac.indptr
Out[114]: array([0, 1], dtype=int32)
In [115]: Ac.indices
Out[115]: array([88], dtype=int32)
```

Math, especially matrix products is done with `csr/csc` formats.  So it may be hard to avoid this 80 TB memory use.

---

Looking at the traceback I see that it's trying to convert `other` to the format that matches self.

So with `A.dot(B)`, and `A` is (1,N) `csr`, the small shape. `B` is (N,1) `csc`, also the small shape.  But `B.tocsr()` requires the large `(N+1,)` shaped `indptr`.

---

Let's try an alternative to `dot`

First 2 matrices:

```
In [122]: A = sparse.random(1,100, .2,format='csr')
In [123]: B = sparse.random(100,1, .2,format='csc')
In [124]: A
Out[124]: 
<1x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [125]: B
Out[125]: 
<100x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [126]: A@B
Out[126]: 
<1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [127]: _.A
Out[127]: array([[1.33661021]])
```

Their nonzero element indices. Only the ones that match matter.

```
In [128]: A.indices, B.indices
Out[128]: 
(array([16, 20, 23, 28, 30, 37, 39, 40, 43, 49, 54, 59, 61, 63, 67, 70, 74,
        91, 94, 99], dtype=int32),
 array([ 5,  8, 15, 25, 34, 35, 40, 46, 47, 51, 53, 60, 68, 70, 75, 81, 87,
        90, 91, 94], dtype=int32))
```

equality matrix:

```
In [129]: mask = A.indices[:,None]==B.indices

In [132]: np.nonzero(mask.any(axis=0))
Out[132]: (array([ 6, 13, 18, 19]),)
In [133]: np.nonzero(mask.any(axis=1))
Out[133]: (array([ 7, 15, 17, 18]),)
```

The matching indices:

```
In [139]: A.indices[Out[133]]
Out[139]: array([40, 70, 91, 94], dtype=int32)
In [140]: B.indices[Out[132]]
Out[140]: array([40, 70, 91, 94], dtype=int32)
```

sum of the corresponding `data` values matches [127]

```
In [141]: (A.data[Out[133]]*B.data[Out[132]]).sum()
Out[141]: 1.3366102138511582
```