# Sparse matrix uses a lot of memory

Tags: python, scipy

I have a program that models a 3D space inside of a 'matrix'. This matrix is supposed to be a list of 2D matrices. Since the space will have at least 1000000 * 1000000 * 10000000 (10^19) places, I decided to use the sparse matrix package from scipy. I have 32GB of RAM but after creating about 3100 matrices I get the error

```
in __init__
    self.indptr = np.zeros(self._swap((M, N))[0] + 1,
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 38.1 MiB for an array with shape (10000001,) and data type int32
```

My understanding was that an empty sparse matrix should use practically no memory. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my program:

```
channelSizeX = 10
channelSizeY = 10
channelSizeZ = 100

SpatialResolutionPerMM = 1000000

stepX = channelSizeX * SpatialResolutionPerMM
stepY = channelSizeY * SpatialResolutionPerMM
stepZ = channelSizeZ * SpatialResolutionPerMM

channel = []

class particle:
    particle_speed = [[]]
    particle_type = 0

    def __init__(self, particle_type, speed, speed_delta):

        self.particle_type = particle_type

    def print_part(self):
        print(self.particle_type, self.particle_location, self.particle_speed)

def create_Channel():

    start = time.time()
    global channel
    for i in range(stepZ):   
        print(str(i) + "\n")  
        new = csr_matrix((stepX, stepY), dtype=particle)
        channel.append(new)
    end = time.time()
    print("Execution time for particle creation: ", end-start)
    
def main():
    create_Channel()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A (n,m) shape matrix requires a (n+1,) shape indptr array.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936291/how-to-dot-product-1-1013-1013-1-scipy-sparse-matrix

Comment: Ah ok, so the data structures aren't dynamically allocated. Is there any way to accomplish this with library functions? A Dictionary Of Keys based sparse matrix maybe?

Comment: I just tried it... with the given size, this would require about 50GB of memory with DOK sparse matrices, which seems to be the smallest one in the library. Any suggestions?

Comment: `dtype=particle` is non-starter.  That's same as `dtype=object`, storing references to external objects as done in a list (or `dict`).  With `numpy` arrays that dtype is virtually a list.  `sparse` may accept that when creating the matrix, but it can't do much with it.  It certainly can't do math.  `sparse` is designed for large linear algebra problems, not compact storage of generic objects.  Test small examples before banging your head against cases that raise memory errors.